# SWR error, it's making multiple calls and data its ever undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch, swr

Hi i'm trying to use SWR in my React app, but this generate an error because the data its ever undefined and when i check the network, i can se three calls to the api:

[image]

[image]

**Table component:**

```
import React, { , useEffect } from "react";
import {ProductService} from "../Services/product-service";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";
import useSWR from "swr";

function TableTransactions({ clientUserName, productNumber }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {data, isLoading, error} = useSWR(["transactions",clientUserName, productNumber,10], 
                                   ProductService.GetListTransactionsByParams(clientUserName, productNumber, 10));

  useEffect(()=>{
    (async()=>{
      //...;
  })();
 },[clientUserName, productNumber]);

 if(error) return <div>failed to load</div>
 if(isLoading) return <LinearProgress/>

return (
<>
  <Box>
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <b>Tipo transacción</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              <b>Fecha</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              <b>Valor</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              <b>Producto origen</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell >
              <b>Producto destino</b>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((row) => (
            <TableRow
              key={uuidv4()}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.typeTransaction.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell >{row.creationDate}</TableCell>
              <TableCell >{row.explicitValue}</TableCell>
              <TableCell >{row.originProductNumber}</TableCell>
              <TableCell >{row.destinyProductNumber}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </Box>    
 </>
);
}
export default TableTransactions;
```

**My function caller fetcher:**

```
async function GetListTransactionsByParams(userName, productNumber, maxCount=10){
 try{
    var objSearch = {clientUserName: userName, productNumber: productNumber, maxCount:maxCount};
    
    let route = ClientSettings.UrlBaseInfoBankApi+"ProductInfo/ListTransactionsClient";
    let bearer = null;

    var response = await fetch(route,{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer,
        },
        //credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(objSearch)
    });

    await HandleResponseService(response);

    let json = await response.clone().json();
    if (response.status == 200 && json.response === true && json.error === "") {
        return json.data;
    }

    return null;
 }catch(err){
    throw new Error("Error connecting or timeout service: "+err);
    return null;
 }
}
```

I try to check {data ? && data.mapa(...)} but this only fix the console error, and data continues ever being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the way to return data from my fetcher function:

```
const GetListTransactionsByParams= async(userName, productNumber, maxCount=10, fromDate, untilDate)=>{
 try{
    //...
    
    let route = ClientSettings.UrlBaseInfoBankApi+"ProductInfo/ListTransactionsClient";
    let bearer = null;

    var response = await fetch(route,{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer,
        },
        //credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(objSearch)
    });

    await HandleResponseServiceFetch(response);
    
    const data = await response.clone().json();
    return data.data;
 }catch(err){
    throw new Error("An error occurred while fetching the data: "+err);
 }
}
```

And i had to change the way to generate a key for swr, apply adittional configuration for avoid automatic re-fetch and use ()=> for apply direct cll to fetcher:

```
function generateKey(clientUserName, productNumber, maxCount) {
  return `${clientUserName}-${productNumber}-${maxCount}`;
}

const key = generateKey(clientUserName, productNumber, maxCount);

const {
 data = [],
 isLoading,
 isValidating,
 error,
 mutate} = useSWR([key],() => ProductService.GetListTransactionsByParams(
    clientUserName,
    productNumber,
    maxCount,
    dateFrom,
    dateUntil
  ),
 {
   revalidateOnFocus: false, 
   revalidateOnReconnect: false, 
 });
```